# Blow someone up

Tags: meaning

From the Coach Carter film.

Basketbal team is reading the paper about their good season.

> (One team member's reading): Surprise arrival to the poll is Richmond
>   High at 19th.
>
> -Top 20, baby
>
> -We're 19th, dog.
>
> (The same player is carry on with reading): The Oilers have posted a
>   perfect 9-0 mark winning on the road against perrenial powerhous
>   Xavier and Baxter Union.
>
> -Yo, Junior, you should read the rest of this. ***They blowing you up in this paper***.

What does blow someone up means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does **not** mean exploding someone with dynamite hahaha!

I don't know if I would call this a common idiom, but the meaning is pretty clear to mossy native speakers. It means the paper is making a big deal out of Junior. The paperis highly praising him, and saying good things about him. They are turning him into a celebrity. A much more common idiom is

> blowing something out of proportion.

This means to "blow something up" (read: make a big deal of) something that isn't very important. Or to exaggerate how important something is.

Comment: Blowing up is part of an incomplete simile **blowing up like a balloon**, but not the point of exploding

Comment: "exploding" could also be said as...  *blowing up*.